# Kusto: How to transform a table to a table where columns and rows are defined by unique values of two columns?

Tags: kql

Say I have a table like this:

| Computer | AppName | AppVersion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | App1 | 1.0 |
| C1 | App2 | 2.0 |
| C2 | App1 | 3.0 |
| C2 | App2 | 4.0 |
| C3 | App1 | 5.0 |
| C3 | App2 | 6.0 |

I'd like to transform it into a table like this:

| Computer | App1 | App2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| C2 | 3.0 | 4.0 |
| C3 | 5.0 | 6.0 |

Is that possible in KQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin) plugin

```
datatable(Computer:string, AppName:string, AppVersion:string)
[
   ,"C1" ,"App1" ,"1.0"
   ,"C1" ,"App2" ,"2.0"
   ,"C2" ,"App1" ,"3.0"
   ,"C2" ,"App2" ,"4.0"
   ,"C3" ,"App1" ,"5.0"
   ,"C3" ,"App2" ,"6.0"
]
| evaluate pivot(AppName, take_any(AppVersion))
```

| Computer | App1 | App2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| C2 | 3.0 | 4.0 |
| C3 | 5.0 | 6.0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUDef83ILSktQiq%20KSosy8dB0Fx4ICv8TcVGR%20WGpRcWZ%20HlRIk5crmpdLQUFBR8nZUAlIAlWAaUM9AyV0CSMQbYQkYYSswxiLBJg2QZIwRtZhikUCrMMMLBHLy1WjkFqWmFOaWJKqUJBZll%20iAfWQjkJJYnZqfGJepQbCS5qaAP7SZzoKAQAA)